# Migrate Azure AD B2C user flows to custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

We are considering to start with the built-in user flows for our application in B2C.  We want to benefit from the standard flows to register users, have forgotten password workflow in place, have MFA, etc...

However, as business requirements for our platform might (and will) change over time, it could be that the standard user flows are not enough and we might need to switch to custom policies over time.

Therefore, we'd like to know if it is possible to have a migration (export/import?) from the standard configured user flows at that moment, to the XML-based custom policies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Azure Portal, go in to your B2C directory, select your user flow, and click the `Download` button at the top, it will download an XML file that contains the 'as is' definition of your `user flow`. You could later on use that for recreating the user flow, though there is no direct "import" option.